# How to use the variable that outside of its loop

Tags: java

I've declare the variable that use to make the row in data table change color when the variable is equal to 0. So this is my code .

```
private String validationField(List<List<TsmTimesheetHdr>> timesheetList) {
    String errorCode = "";

    if (isOverLimitPerDay()) {
        errorCode = MessageConst.CIELO_APP_ERR_00013;
    }

    for (List<TsmTimesheetHdr> list : timesheetList) {
        int count = 0;
        boolean isTimeEntry = false;
        for (TsmTimesheetHdr hdr : list) {
            if (count++ == 0) {
                if (Utils.isEmpty(hdr.getProjectCode()) || Utils.isEmpty(hdr.getActivity())
                        || Utils.isEmpty(hdr.getTaskCode())) {
                    errorCode = MessageConst.CIELO_APP_ERR_00003;
                    hdr.setIsValid("0");
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    hdr.setIsValid("1");
                }
            }
            if (hdr.getHoursSpend() != 0.0) {
                isTimeEntry = true;
            }

        }

        if (!Utils.isEmpty(errorCode))
            continue;
        if (!isTimeEntry) {
            errorCode = MessageConst.CIELO_APP_ERR_00002;
            break;
        }
    }

    return errorCode;
}
```

how can i use back the hdr in this if statement

```
            if (!isTimeEntry) {
            errorCode = MessageConst.CIELO_APP_ERR_00002;
            break;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** you are doing this validation:

```
if (!isTimeEntry) {
errorCode = MessageConst.CIELO_APP_ERR_00002;
break;
}
```

For a **specific** `hdr` object then you have to identify when you will recognize this `hdr` object in your *loop*, once it is identified then asign this `hdr` to a local variable, then use this variable in your validation ...

Something like:

```
private String validationField(List<List<TsmTimesheetHdr>> timesheetList) {
    String errorCode = "";
    TsmTimesheetHdr  distinctHdr;

    // for loop ...
     // for loop [
         if(hdr.meets_criteria()){
            distinctHdr = hdr;
         }
    ]

   // the use this obj for your validation
if (!isTimeEntry) {
errorCode = MessageConst.CIELO_APP_ERR_00002;
// now you have acccess ...
doSomethingWithHdrs(distictHdr);
break;
}
```

**if** your validation is for **all** `hdr` objects, then move your

```
if (!isTimeEntry) {
errorCode = MessageConst.CIELO_APP_ERR_00002;
break;
}
```

In to the loop.

Hope I understood your question, gl.

Comment: if the isValid is in the hdr file . so how can i set the isValid to 0

Comment: well from your code, shouldn't it be `distinctHdr.setIsValid("0")` ?

Comment: i already use `distinctHdr.setIsValid("0")` its say The local variable distincthdr may not have been initialized

Comment: i think if i make the `TsmTimesheetHdr  distinctHdr;` to `TsmTimesheetHdr  distinctHdr = new tsmTimesheetHdr();` will do it ?

Comment: Why would you want that ?  the `hdr` object already exists in the list that you are iterating through

Comment: since the `hdr` is in the for loop . need to initialize the `distincthdr` since its outside from the for loop . am i right ?

Comment: okay now i already got it . i initialize the `distincthdr` inside the `if (count++ == 0) {` if statement . thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

You save hdr into original list and use these list accordingly. See sample

```
    for (List<TsmTimesheetHdr> list : timesheetList) {
            int count = 0;
            boolean isTimeEntry = false;
            for (TsmTimesheetHdr hdr : list) {
                if (count++ == 0) {
                    if (Utils.isEmpty(hdr.getProjectCode()) || Utils.isEmpty(hdr.getActivity())
                            || Utils.isEmpty(hdr.getTaskCode())) {
                        errorCode = MessageConst.CIELO_APP_ERR_00003;
                        hdr.setIsValid("0");
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        hdr.setIsValid("1");
                    }
                }
                if (hdr.getHoursSpend() != 0.0) {
                    isTimeEntry = true;
                }  
            }

            if (!Utils.isEmpty(errorCode)) {
                continue;
             }

            if (!isTimeEntry) {
                     list.get(count).setIsValid("0") 
                     errorCode = MessageConst.CIELO_APP_ERR_00002;
                     break;                       
             }

            }
        }
```

Comment: from my code . i just want to use the `hdr` instead of the list . i want to set the `isValid` variable inside `tsmTimesheetHdr` file to 0

Comment: do you need hdr with projectCode empty is more than one or only first one?? I mean when you found hdr with projectCode empty then you put isValid = 0 and break the loop.

Comment: just now for the part `if (Utils.isEmpty(hdr.getProjectCode()) || Utils.isEmpty(hdr.getActivity())
                            || Utils.isEmpty(hdr.getTaskCode())) {
                        errorCode = MessageConst.CIELO_APP_ERR_00003;
                        hdr.setIsValid("0");
                        continue;
                    }
                    else {
                        hdr.setIsValid("1");
                    }` its already done . i just want to set isValid equal to 0 in this if statement `if (!isTimeEntry) {
errorCode = MessageConst.CIELO_APP_ERR_00002;
break;
}`

Comment: not clear what you need. I believe hdr with projectCode empty is more than one. if you need only one then you can overwrite hdr.

Comment: like this , i want to set the `isValid` in the last if statement . i use it to change the row color in datatable . so my question is i want to use back the `hdr` in the last if statement for me to set `isValid` equal to 0

Comment: I think your can retrieve from first loop list. I believe you already inserted isValid value in second loop.So you can retrieve the value from first loop list